# Are the peer-reviewers of papers submitted to a conference that took a place in location X from X too?

Tags: peer-review, conference

Generally speaking, are the papers submitted to a conference (Scientific conference, say) that took place in region/country X reviewed by peer-reviewers in region/country X?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the reviewers could easily be from other countries and may, or even may not, be attending the conference.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not necessary and also impractical. Conferences have different chairs and different sessions. Each is controlled by a different person. There are multiple layers to it. In general, reviewers are spread all across the world. And same reviewers do their job across multiple years.